# JavaScript Hide/Show Animation

Tags: javascript

I would like to click on my image and have it disappear and move to the right in a different location.  Currently, my image runs off the screen to the right.  Please help me to create a code using the `timeout()` that allows my image to hide and show.

```
php code
<div id= "ben" style= "position: relative; visibility: visible;" onclick="moveRight()" >
<img src = "images/ben.JPG" height = "250" width = "200" alt= "Picture of Peek-a-boo Ben"/>


//JavaScript for a hide/show image in different location
var ben = null;
var animate ;
function init(){
   ben = document.getElementById('ben');
   ben.style.position= 'relative'; 
   ben.style.left = '0px'; 
}
function moveRight(){
   ben.style.left = parseInt(ben.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
   animate = setTimeout(moveRight,20); // call moveRight in 20msec
}
function stop(){
   clearTimeout(animate);
   ben.style.left = '0px'; 
}
window.onload =init;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using JQuery?

Comment: jQuery.animate() looks fairly straightforward:  "The .animate() method allows us to create animation effects on any numeric CSS property."  http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Check out my edit to my answer....showing you a Jquery version....you can choose which one you wanna use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely personally use jquery for this....

But if you want it in pure javascript, here it is....albeit the animation is done using CSS.

```
//JavaScript for a hide/show image in different location
var ben = null;
var animate=0 ;
function init(){
  ben = document.getElementById('ben');
 }

 function toggled(){

  var image = document.getElementById('image2');
  if( animate==0){
   animate = 1;
  image.className= "right";} 
  else if(animate==1){
   animate=0;
  image.className= "left";}
 }

 window.onload =init;
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/bnDgk/)....just adjust the From and To in the CSS to move it further or closer

And the relevant CSS...

```
.right {
-webkit-transform: translateX(150px);
-webkit-animation-name: right;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

.left {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
-webkit-animation-name: left;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
 @-webkit-keyframes right { from { -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
 to {  -webkit-transform: translateX(150px);  }}

 @-webkit-keyframes left { from { -webkit-transform: translateX(150px); }
 to {  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);  }}
```

**EDIT**

This is it using JQuery...with no CSS Required.....All those lines of code above ^^ reduced to two.....gotta love Jquery :)  It actually could get even simpler using the built in toggle() function to.......

```
var tog=0;
$('#ben').click(function(){
if(tog==0){$('#image2').animate({marginLeft: "250"}, 1500);tog=1; return false;}
else if(tog==1){$('#image2').animate({marginLeft: "0"}, 1500);tog=0; return false;
} });
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/bnDgk/2/)

(note... you have to include the Jquery library, and call $(document).ready(function(){ if you plan on using this code...

Also, you dont have to do onclick in your HTML anymore...

```
ie... <div onclick="moveRight()">
```

As Jquery's handling it for you, using click()